# Why am I getting garbage value from a function call?

Tags: c, return-value, garbage

I am doing problem FARIDA on spoj using recursion with memoization in C as per [this link](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FARIDA) . In the following code I am getting a garbage value for variable `t2` on calling the function solve.I am pasting the image of the printed value of `t2` on the console. After checking 3-4 times I am unable to find what is causing that behaviour. Please help me with this. Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>

long int a[1000];
long int cache[1000];
int n;


long int max(long int a,long int b)
{
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else
    return b;
}


long int solve(int i)
{
    //printf("%d\n",i);
    long int t1,t2,t;
    if(i>(n-1)){
            printf("i=====%d n=====%d\n",i,n);
        return 0;
    }
     if(cache[i]!=-1)
        return cache[i];

    t1=solve(i+2); // i+2 because we cant get a coin from the monster i+1.
    t2=solve(i+3); 
    printf("t1::: %lld t2::: %lld\n", t1, t2);
    t = max(t1,t2)+a[i];
    cache[i] = t;
    printf("i::: %d t::: %lld\n", i, t);
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    int t,i;
    long int answer;
    scanf("%d",&t);// no. of test case
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf(" %d", &n); //no. of monsters.

       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
            a[i] = 0;
            cache[i] = -1;
            scanf(" %lld", &a[i]);//no. of coins each monster can give
        }
        answer = solve(0);
        printf("%lld\n",answer);
    }
}
```

This is the output on the console showing the printed where t=10 and n = 8

```
10
8
218 8 15 22 29 115 2100 2000
i=====8 n=====8
i=====9 n=====8
t1::: 0 t2::: 11008688374415360  // here t2 should be equal to 0 but thats not the case
i::: 6 t::: 2100
i=====9 n=====8
i=====10 n=====8
t1::: 0 t2::: 11008688374415360
i::: 7 t::: 2000
t1::: 8589934594100 t2::: 9222668349412999168
i::: 4 t::: 2129
i=====8 n=====8
t1::: 2000 t2::: 9222668349412999168
i::: 5 t::: 2115
t1::: 9083855833169 t2::: 8594672046007986432
i::: 2 t::: 8595446443790043232
t1::: 9019431323715 t2::: 8594672046007986432
i::: 3 t::: 8595446443790043225
t1::: 9178345113696 t2::: 8594672048301670398
i::: 0 t::: -8589932230
9851160328407354
```

Comment: to start with, please put comprehensive instructions to user for input type and values.

Comment: I have added comments in my code so that others can understand but in the output i m only showing the printed value.

Comment: not in code, in runtime, on-screen instruction, using `printf()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use correct format specifier with `printf()`. Check the below code.

For `long int`, the specifier is `%ld`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

long int a[1000];
long int cache[1000];
int n;


long int max(long int a,long int b)
{
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else
    return b;
}


long int solve(int i)
{
    //printf("%d\n",i);
    long int t1,t2,t;
    if(i>(n-1)){
            printf("i=====%d n=====%d\n",i,n);
        return 0;
    }
     if(cache[i]!=-1)
        return cache[i];

    t1=solve(i+2);
    t2=solve(i+3);
    printf("t1::: %ld t2::: %ld\n", t1, t2);
    t = max(t1,t2)+a[i];
    cache[i] = t;
    printf("i::: %d t::: %ld\n", i, t);
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    int t,i;
    long int answer;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf(" %d", &n);

       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
            a[i] = 0;
            cache[i] = -1;
            scanf(" %ld", &a[i]);
        }
        answer = solve(0);
        printf("%ld\n",answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. My bad I had read somewhere it was %lld so didnt bother to look there.

Comment: @user3259930 Welcome!!  If this answer has helped you solve your issue, you can consider accepting it by clicking on accept `tick` on top left side of the answer.

Comment: Ya sorry I forgot about that. Thank you again!